# LibGDX: I need to get from SpriteBatch to Batch in order to draw a Touchpad

Tags: android, libgdx, spritebatch

I have created a little game using LibGDX and it uses a SpriteBatch when it renders the game objects. Now I want to add a Touchpad to it, and the draw method of Touchpad takes a Batch as a parameter, but my game uses SpriteBatch.
What can I do?

Comment: The class SpriteBatch implements the interface Batch, so it is an instance of it that can just be passed as the parameter. This is called polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Because `SpriteBatch` implements `Batch` this means it can be used wherever a function requires a `Batch`. So when you call `Touchpad#draw(batch)` you can give it your `SpriteBatch` instance and it will work just fine. You should probably read up on [polymorphism in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).